# What does this quote mean in 4 sentences?

Tags: meaning

"The secret of health for both mind and body is not to mourn for the past, worry about the future, or anticipate troubles but to live in the present moment wisely and earnestly." (Buddha)

Comment: What do you mean by *"in 4 sentens"*. Are you giving us homework?

Answer (score 2):

You will be healthier if you don't worry and focus on the present.

You will be healthier if you don't worry and focus on the present.

You will be healthier if you don't worry and focus on the present.

You will be healthier if you don't worry and focus on the present.